# IBMQ: "Credentials are already in use"

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Executing the following:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import IBMQ, QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
```

I get the following error which I do not know what to do about, does anybosy know what I can do?

```
ibmqfactory.load_account:WARNING:2020-11-27 
13:08:45,170: Credentials are already in use. The 
existing account in the session will be replaced.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **NOT** an error.

It just means that you have loaded your account previously, maybe from the previous run. It will just replace your previous credential... and shouldn't cause any issue.